# Weight Detection Under Concrete/Asphalt

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity

Consider that a weight sensor was embedded in a road. Would cars that drive over it trigger the sensor?

I was thinking it'd look something like this (if we ignored the downward force that the concrete/asphalt put on the sensor)

Blue = Road
Black = Asphalt/Concrete
Red = Where the sensors are placed
Purple = Sensor
Orange = Some weight
Since the outline may not be clear, the sensor is 100% submerged in the asphalt/concrete.

[image]

Would both sensors detect the total amount of force on the road or would it not detect it at all since the sensor is inside the asphalt/concrete and is laid on top of the ground?

Comment: This depends on the sensors and how they are embedded, I'm afraid. Also, the distribution of force will depend similarly on the structure. You'd need more information here about how the road surface and sensors are constructed.

Comment: Precision scales for cars and trucks exist. They simply make a small cut in the surface to keep the force on a segment of the scale well defined.

Answer (score 1):

First off, there would have to be a force transfer between the road (blue) into the asphalt (black) beneath it for the sensor to trigger. We need to view the road as not infinitely rigid, it's somewhat "squishy", which allows force transfer at and near to the point(s) of contact. The ability for the force at one point to communicate to the other point depends on a few conditions, e.g. the rigidity/stiffness of the road, how far away the sensors are from each other, etc. A more rigid road surface and closely spaced sensors would create conditions that are better at transferring the force from one sensor to another.